# applications of mutation testing

Tags: mutation-testing

what are different applications of mutation testing?

Comment: I wrote an article explaining the advantages of MT: https://pedrorijo.com/blog/intro-mutation/ hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Mutation testing is used to "test your test cases".  The idea is to make small mutations to your application and then run your tests to make sure they catch the bugs added by these mutations.

There is a good explanation with examples posted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing).